# Html code for displaying a group of images on all viewing platforms

Tags: html

I am using html to display a number of images on a website. I want to display  6 images now but to be able to add more images. I would like them to appear neatly (so I have adjusted their heights to be the same) on both desktop and mobile. I don't mind how many appear per row but my current code shows them with random gaps between them which doesn't look too good. Centralised would be best too. I am new to coding. Thank you.

I am using EKM to host my site so I am cutting and pasting my html code into their source page.

```
<img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
<img src="img2.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
<img src="img3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
<img src="img4.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
<img src="img5.jpg" style="width: 250px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
<img src="img6.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px, padding:5px;"></a>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can depends on what size of images expect to show. I suggest to separate css from html but you can try this:

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 30%;">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/katzenworld.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/funny-cat.jpeg?fit=1020%2C1020&ssl=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are new to coding I will keep it simple how about using following piece of code. It will show one image in a row, centralized.

```
<center>
<img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>
<br />

<center>
<img src="img2.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>

<br />

<center>
<img src="img3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>

<br />

<center>
<img src="img4.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>

<br />

<center>
<img src="img5.jpg" style="width: 250px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>

<br />

<center>
<img src="img6.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:5px;"></a>
</center>
```

You can do a lot better than this using bootstrap and other styling methods, but this is very basic styling you can do. Here are the things I Changed in your code.

1. Remove &nbsp(); - why you need it, it is used for spacing and doesn't make sense here.
2. Add `<center>` tag - simply put the element in center of a parent element
3. Add `<br />` - Means break line goes to new line.
4. you had written comma instead of semicolon after specifying height. I fixed it.

that's all, happy coding !

Comment: The [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag was made obsolete ages ago and should not be recommended.